# C# Pattern for abstract class specific code

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I have an abstract "Action" class, which has derived types of ActionAppointment, ActionCall, ActionEmail, and ActionLetter.  I'm trying to write a function that will DRY up our service layer, so we're not writing CRUD calls 5 times anymore.

I have in our service layer some update logic (lots of other code removed for brevity):

```
private IServiceResponse UpdateAction<T>(T action, string originalActionStatus) where T : Action
{
        if (action.GetType() == typeof(Action))
        {
            _actionRepository.Update(action);
        }
        else if (action.GetType() == typeof(ActionAppointment))
        {
            _actionAppointmentRepository.Update(action as ActionAppointment);
        }
        else if (action.GetType() == typeof(ActionCall))
        {
            _actionCallRepository.Update(action as ActionCall);
        }
        else if (action.GetType() == typeof(ActionEmail))
        {
            _actionEmailRepository.Update(action as ActionEmail);
        }
        else if (action.GetType() == typeof(ActionLetter))
        {
            _actionLetterRepository.Update(action as ActionLetter);
        }
}
```

Unfortunately, how our repositories are setup, I have to use the specifically named repositories (ie. I can not update an ActionLetter through the _actionRepository even though it derives from Action)

I have been reading on different patterns, and it sounds like something similar to a Factory Pattern, but I can't see how to make it work.

Am I missing something stupid?

Comment: You might consider the *Visitor* pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: Yes a factory pattern is a solution.  Your Repositories must either have a common base class or implement an interface.  They must all have an Update method that accepts the object typed as Action.  The factory accepts the type as a parameter (in whatever form, name, type, enum if one is available) and returns the correct repository.  That is pretty much it.  Is there a specific point of confusion on how to implement the Factory?

Comment: I'm unsure how to implement a factory pattern for this one, since IRepository is generic based on each domain model object.

Comment: Sorry for slow response.  A factory will not work with generics they are not type polymorphic.  Generics are based on parametric polymorphism.  It is a functional scope polymorphism.  Factories require class scope polymorphism.  Not sure I understand what you get out of this design beyond more type safety for basic updates etc? I use nHibernate it has an untyped Update anyway.  I opt for a base Repository class with a common Update, and add some minimal typing - all my persisted objects have a single common base class, so i can't pass e.g net type as object that is not valid for persisting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can't you just write an overload of that method for each action type? Forget the `<T>` and `typeof` stuff - what you're doing is implementing a built-in language feature (method overloading) by hand, and in a fragile way too.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what polymorphism and inheritance is all about.

Comment: The code was previously written as a method for each Action type.  I am just trying to DRY it up some, but I guess maybe I can DRY up some of the shared components, but have the specific repository code in each one.

Comment: @Matt: Your if-else contraption isn't making the code any DRYer, that's for sure.

Answer (score -2):

Let's inverse the logic here:

```
abstract class Action {
    protected abstract Repository GetRepository();
    protected void Update(){
       this.GetRepository().Update(this);
    }
}
```

All you have to do is override the GetRepository in each of the deriving classes. For example:

```
class ActionAppointment : Action {
    protected override Repository GetRepository() {
        return _actionAppointmentRepository;
    }
}
```

Comment: not a very good idea for a model class to know about how its stored.

Comment: -1, Injecting services (even repositories) into domain objects is a bad practice.

Comment: Agreed with smartcaveman.  It violates our rules to have that type of dependency.